# KryptonSeparator resizing issue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, krypton-toolkit, krypton

> Scenario

I'm in need of help using a [KryptonSeparator](http://www.componentfactory.com/blog/2009/05/kryptonseparator/).

I would like to use the separator in the image below to resize the width of the left and right controls:

[image]

> Problem

The problem is when I try to move the separator to the left then it creates a very disturbing visual effect, and more or less the same thing happens when I move the separator to the right, but to the left is much more appreciable (and horrible):

[image]

I think that I'm not using properly the eventargs of the `KryptonSeparator` because when I move the separator to the left I'm basing the calculations using the separator's width instead the event data (because I don't know how to do it properly).

> Question

What modifications I should do in my code to fix the resizing problem?

> Code

Both the left and the right control has a `MinimumSize` property assigned, I'm trying to stop the resize if `MinimumSize.Width` is reached.

This is the source code, in VB.Net:

```
''' <summary>
''' Handles the SplitterMoving event of the KryptonSeparator1 control.
''' </summary>
Private Sub KryptonSeparator1_SplitterMoving(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SplitterCancelEventArgs) _
Handles KryptonSeparator1.SplitterMoving

    Dim separator As KryptonSeparator = DirectCast(sender, KryptonSeparator)
    Dim leftCtrl As Control = Control1
    Dim rightCtrl As Control = Control2

    If (e.MouseCursorX > 0) _
    AndAlso Not ((rightCtrl.Size.Width - e.MouseCursorX) < rightCtrl.MinimumSize.Width) Then

        separator.Location = New Point(separator.Location.X + e.MouseCursorX, separator.Location.Y)
        leftCtrl.Width += e.MouseCursorX
        rightCtrl.Width -= e.MouseCursorX
        rightCtrl.Left = separator.Right

    ElseIf (e.MouseCursorX < 0) _
    AndAlso Not ((leftCtrl.Size.Width + e.MouseCursorX - separator.Width) < leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width) Then

        separator.Location = New Point(separator.Location.X - separator.Width, separator.Location.Y)
        leftCtrl.Width -= separator.Width
        rightCtrl.Width += separator.Width
        rightCtrl.Left = separator.Right

    End If

End Sub
```

This is the source code, in C#:

```
/// Handles the SplitterMoving event of the KryptonSeparator1 control.
/// </summary>
private void KryptonSeparator1_SplitterMoving(object sender, SplitterCancelEventArgs e)
{
    KryptonSeparator separator = (KryptonSeparator)sender;
    FolderView leftCtrl = this.FolderView_Files;
    KryptonListBox rightCtrl = this.KryptonListBox_Files;

    if ((e.MouseCursorX > 0) && !((rightCtrl.Size.Width - e.MouseCursorX) < rightCtrl.MinimumSize.Width)) {
        separator.Location = new Point(separator.Location.X + e.MouseCursorX, separator.Location.Y);
        leftCtrl.Width += e.MouseCursorX;
        rightCtrl.Width -= e.MouseCursorX;
        rightCtrl.Left = separator.Right;


    } else if ((e.MouseCursorX < 0) && !((leftCtrl.Size.Width + e.MouseCursorX - separator.Width) < leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width)) {
        separator.Location = new Point(separator.Location.X - separator.Width, separator.Location.Y);
        leftCtrl.Width -= separator.Width;
        rightCtrl.Width += separator.Width;
        rightCtrl.Left = separator.Right;

    }

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

> UPDATE

I've updated the codes above to simplify the reading, and I'm sharing this new video where you can see the design problem:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MhmyE3MZX0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MhmyE3MZX0)

Comment: Can you grab the other "visual effect" separators? Because if so, it can be because you define a separator everytime you drag.

Comment: Please, see the code example or the video at the bottom of the question, you'll see that the effect only remains while I'm moving the (unique) separator and only when I move it to the left. thanks for comment!

Comment: Why dont you use *MouseCursorX* for both directions? It works for the right one.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε yes I think that is where I fail, just because moving it to the left I've tried to calculate it using MouseCursorX but I didn't get the expected result, maths are not my best. sorry for my english

Comment: Two questions: 1. If you are handling the *SplitterMoving* event why do you manually set the *seperator* location also? Aren't splitter and seperator the same control? 2. What *e.MouseCursorX* represents?

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε 1) Yes they are the same control, but the event does not makes the control to be moved, the event is only fired to let the user move manually the controls using/calculating the eventdata args. 2) `MousecursorX`: `Gets the X coordinate of the mouse pointer in client coordinates.`, also it has other property: `SplitX`: `Gets or sets the X coordinate of the upper left corner of the System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer in client coordinates`. And of course also has a `MouseCursorY` and `SplitY`.

Comment: That is explained in the first url of my question: As the user moves the mouse over the control it changes the mouse cursor to indicate that it provides splitter functionality. If you press the mouse and start dragging then you see feedback drawn over the application that shows what change will occur if you release the mouse.

Comment: The KryptonSeparator does not actually do anything when you release the mouse at the end of the drag as there is no way for the control to know what other controls should be resized and positioned. Instead it generates events that you can monitor and once the drag ends you use that event to decide what action to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to get where the user clicked before the dragging,`mouse down event of splitter control` and `total width` of three controls:

```
Private mouse_Down As Point //you can use an integer also because y coordinate remains the same
Private totalWidth As Integer

//mouse down event
mouse_Down.X = e.MouseCursorX
totalWidth = seperator.Width + LeftControl.Width + RightControl.Width

Private Sub KryptonSeparator1_SplitterMoving(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SplitterCancelEventArgs) Handles KryptonSeparator1.SplitterMoving

    Dim separator As KryptonSeparator = DirectCast(sender, KryptonSeparator)
    Dim leftCtrl As Control = Control1
    Dim rightCtrl As Control = Control2
    Dim leftWidth, rightWidth As Integer

    leftWidth = leftCtrl.Width + (e.MouseCursorX - mouse_Down.X)
    rightWidth = rightCtrl.Width - (e.MouseCursorX - mouse_Down.X)

    If leftWidth <= leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width Then
        leftCtrl.Width = leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width
        separator.Left = leftCtrl.Left + leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width
        rightCtrl.Left = leftCtrl.Left + leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width + separator.Width
        rightCtrl.Width = totalWidth - leftCtrl.MinimumSize.Width - separator.Width

        Return
    End If

    If rightWidth <= rightCtrl.MinimumSize.Width Then
        leftCtrl.Width = totalWidth - rightCtrl.MinimumSize.Width - separator.Width
        separator.Left = leftCtrl.Left + leftCtrl.Width
        rightCtrl.Left = leftCtrl.Left + leftCtrl.Width + separator.Width
        rightCtrl.Width = rightCtrl.MinimumSize.Width

        Return
    End If

    separator.Left += (e.MouseCursorX - mouse_Down.X)
    leftCtrl.Width = leftWidth
    rightCtrl.Width = rightWidth
    rightCtrl.Left = leftCtrl.Left + leftWidth + separator.Width

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
//mouse down event
//mouse_Down.X = e.MouseCursorX
mouse_Down.X = MousePosition.X
mouse_Down.Y = MousePosition.Y
mouse_Down = seperator.PointToClient(mouse_Down)

totalWidth = seperator.Width + LeftControl.Width + RightControl.Width
```

and in `SplitterMoving`:

```
Dim leftWidth, rightWidth As Integer
Dim pnt As Point

pnt.X = MousePosition.X
pnt.Y = MousePosition.Y

pnt = seperator.PointToClient(pnt)

//replace e.MouseCursorX with pnt.X
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Your logic of resizing the two windows have two minor bugs:

1. Using `e.MouseCursorX` to determine the direction of the resizing(left or right) is wrong, *eg* you move the cursor to the *left(left direction)*, 
   remaining inside the separator, `e.MouseCursorX` is still *positive*, so you are resizing to the *right*(until of course e.MouseCursorX becomes negative) 
   instead of *left* !
2. Your code checks for the minimum size but **does nothing** when the comparison is *false*, meaning when the resulting size of the control is smaller.
   When that happens you need to actually set the size of the control *eg* lets say the minimum size is *50* and the controls size is *55*. If the resize is very fast, the resulting size of the control may become *49*. Your code does nothing(comparison is false) and the size of 
   the control remains *55* instead of seting it to *50*.

My solution solves both of these situations. However, the real issue of your *horible effect* as you said is not these two bugs. It is actually,
the way too *slow responsiveness* of the application, when you resize the controls. To be more specific, when you **resize** and **move** the *right 
control(ListBox_Files)*. You can check it your self if you drag and drop a small number(1 or 2) of files and see the result. It is a tremendous 
difference. That unfortunately tells me that you can not do anything about it. You need to change the logic of the resize. Two solutions:

1. Use one control and custom draw everything, text, icons, vertical-horizontal scrollbars etc.. (not recommended!)
2. Do what visual studio and other application is doing. Do not resize the controls until you release the button. Just show a vertical line:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it does not work, when I click the separator it is moved some pixels to the right and then I can't move it more to any side. where I should put the two instructions that you left outside the sub? maybe I'm failling with that bcause The MouseDown event of the separator does not sends a MouseCursorX.

Comment: One question because your other questions: Are you using the KryptonToolkit to test the results?, if not then you can find the necessary in my sourcecode also with the separator and all that: http://www.mediafire.com/download/1ynuba8zd6uqnqa/BakgroundWorker.rar

Comment: @ElektroStudios I dont have *KryptonToolkit* thats why I dont know the events. In a winform control, in mouse down event there is `e.X and e.Y coordinates`. I thought that there where the same as *SplitterMoving* thats why I used `e.MouseCursorX`. Change it to *e.X*

Comment: I did it, but happens the same of my comment above :(. anyways it says that the e.X is the mouse coordinates as is

Comment: @ElektroStudios Remove the two *if* statements and see if the same is happening

Comment: yes, the same happens removing them, I wonder you have an idea of why is happening this. PS: The source code could help you because inside is the krypton lib and is the application of this question, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Tested and did the changes you've said, but still happens the same, I just can move the separator some pixels to right side, after that I can't move the separator more to any side.

Comment: @ElektroStudios See the values of `mouse_Down.X` and 'pnt.X' while dragging. Use a textbox: `textbox.Text = mouse_Down.X.ToString() + "  " + pnt.X.ToString()`

Comment: Sorry I dont have more time, we continue tomorrow, thanks for the help!